# Hana JBDC connection gives a valid connection for non existing db

Tags: java, jdbc, hana

Ia m using JDBC to connect to Hana from my Java application.

I am using `com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver` as driver and `jdbc:sap://hostName:portNumber/` as connection URL.

This url gives a valid connection when I give an invalid db name.

I tried by appending `?databaseName` and `?currentscheme` but same result.

Comment: I don't know hana, but `jdbc:sap://hostName:portNumber/` looks like a connection url to connect to the server **without a specific database**.

Comment: yeah that's what i mentioned at the bottom i tried by appending databaseName and  currentscheme and given db value. Then also its not working.

Answer (score 0):

For the connection only the correct node/ip address and port are required.
If the currentschema or currentdb are invalid the default schema for the user is used.